# button does not show up when navigating

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, ionic-framework

Hi There I have a code for a working back button but it requires adding in a constructor but I already have one can someone suggest how to fix the issue here my code below. I have a Constuctor already that is for my navigating pages, but its not working to have both in at the same time. trying to fix the issue by having them separated by comas but not working. I also need more words to write here for stack overflow im sorry

Thanks
Adam

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RegformPage } from 'src/app/regform/regform.page';
import { CreditcardPage } from 'src/app/creditcard/creditcard.page';
import {IonRouterOutlet} from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.page.scss'],
})
export class FormsPage implements OnInit {
canGoBack: boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router,routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canGoBack = this.routerOutlet &&
                         this.routerOutlet.canGoBack();
  }

  regform(){
  this.router.navigate(['/regform']);
  }
  ccform(){
  this.router.navigate(['creditcard']);
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
   <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button *ngIf="canGoBack"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title align="center">Forms</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

       <ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title align="center">Registration Form</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>

  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-button align="center" (click)="regform()" color="primary">Get Started</ion-button>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>



    <ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title align="center">Credit Card Form</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>

  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-button align="center" (click)="ccform()" color="primary">Get Started</ion-button>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>


    <ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title align="center">Equipment Rental Form</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>

  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-button align="center"class="reg" color="primary">Get Started</ion-button>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title align="center">Field Trip Form</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>

  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-button align="center"class="reg" color="primary">Get Started</ion-button>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ion-back-button` Documentation says:

> "It is smart enough to know what to render based on the mode and when
>   to show based on the navigation stack."

You don't need to do that manually. Simply put ion-back-button in your template and it should hide itself when the navigation stack has only 1 page.

**Doing it manually:**
If the "smart" enough ion-back-button doesn't hide itself automatically, then as a last resot, add the following css to `global.scss` file.

```
 ion-back-button {
      display: none;
    }

.can-go-back {
    ion-back-button {
      display: block !important;
    }
  }
```

Ionic framework adds .can-go-back class to the `ion-back-button` based on the navigation stack.

Comment: But how can the code work to know that you want it to go back?